# How to Implement pm2 with Docker with node.js

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I want to implement pm2 for node service using Docker.

I have performed following steps for the pm2 implementation

In **Package.json**

Added dependency

`"pm2": "^2.7.0",`

and

`"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "pm2-docker process.yml --watch"
  },`

Added **process.yml**
`apps:
  - script: 'server.js'
    name: 'pm2-docker'`

In **Dockerfile**

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2-docker-alpine:latest

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PORT

ENV PORT $PORT
ENV ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT

RUN apt-get update -qq


RUN apt-get install --yes curl
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential vim


RUN mkdir /database_service
ADD . /database_service
WORKDIR /database_service

RUN npm install -g path
RUN npm cache clean

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD [ "npm", "start", $PORT, $ENVIRONMENT ]
```

am I missing something here or configure something wrong.

Comment: Here https://github.com/keymetrics/docker-pm2 they gave sample scripts, you can verify your script with them

Comment: Can you post the log message?